# Pandas, Convert dataframe to start and end date

Tags: python, pandas

everybody, usually i can solve problems reading already postedquestions, but this time I couldn't. So, my first question.

I have a Pandas DataFrame (converted from .xlsx) with a large (>20000) number of rows, like this

```
> id  sex  age  date  swab outcome death_day
```

For each *id* i have a bunch of lines
I would like to get a pandas with

```
> id  sex  age  first_POSITIVE_date(or null)  last_DATE_swab_outcome death_day
```

I can do it with Excel, but it will take a very long time due to duplicates ID, it is there a way to get it with pandas?

I have created a csv reachable at [csv](http://units-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/personal/s154174_ds_units_it/Documents/pandas.csv?d=wb082f81e1bd94f009177d153c3b94e00&csf=1&web=1&e=WGPJs0)

EDIT: ok, i'll try
now it's like

```
  > id  sex  age  date  swab outcome death_day 
  > 1   M     56   01/04/2020  Neg    Na
  > 2   F     50   01/04/2020  Pos    Na
  > 2   F     50   15/04/2020  Neg    Na
  > 3   M     78  15/04/2020  Neg    Na
  > 1   M     56   15/04/2020  Pos    Na
  > 2   F     50   16/04/2020  Neg    Na
  > 1   M     56   20/04/2020  Neg    Na
```

and wanted is

```
  > id  sex  age  first_POSITIVE_date(or null)  last_DATE swab_outcome death_day
  > 1   M     56   15/04/2020      20/04/2020   Pos       Na
  > 2   F     50   01/04/2020      16/04/2020   Neg       Na
  > 3   M     78   na              15/04/2020   Neg       Na
```

Comment: if you could paste a snip of data with expected output, it'll be really easy to solve it for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is what you would want:

> `although you should share your data snippet in such a way that doesn't require people to log on to sharepoint`

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df_1 = df[df['swab']=='Positive'].groupby(['id','sex','age','death_day'],as_index=False)\
                                 .agg({'date':'min'})
df_1.columns = ['id','sex','age','death_day','first_positive_date']
df_2 = df[['id','date','swab outcome']].drop_duplicates()
df_2.columns = ['id','last_date','last_date_swab_outcome']
df = df[['id','sex','age','death_day']].drop_duplicates()
df = df.merge(df_1,how='left')
df = df.merge(df_2,how='left')
df.head()
```

Comment: Ok i Will try during weekend and tell you